# tcpdump traffic in network namespaces in `net=host` dockercontainer

Tags: networking, tcpdump, network-namespaces

I am trying to capture a tcpdump of a set of processes running in the mininet network emulation framework.

Mininet works by putting each process/set of processes into its own network namespace and then connecting each network namespace via [veth](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/veth.4.html) devices.

What I am trying to do is to take a tcpdump to get a bandwidth usage over time graph. This is however not the hard bit.

What I would expect is that I could just do `sudo tcpdump host 10.0.0.1` (`10.0.0.1` being one of the emulated nodes) to capture all the traffic flowing between the namespaces. However, I am getting `0` packets captured.

I have previously gotten this working, however I cannot remember how. Mininet is running inside the mininet docker container with `net=host`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that tcpdump was picking up the docker0 interface rather than looking on everything.

Correct command was `tcpdump -i any host 10.0.0.1`